# Where to put credentials.json in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-signin

I have made a project involving Google Login.

The file downloaded was credentials.json.

Where do I put this?

Since when this has been changed from google-services.json

Note: I am not using Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common place is in your `project_folder/app` folder.

Comment: didn't work.. also the schema for google-services.json and credentials.json is different.

Comment: This didnt solve my problem either. App still says "Resource not found". Any help?

Comment: You don't need the credentials.json file to add basic google sign in to your app ... i remember for firebase is there a similar aproach (google-service.json). in this case, you must find a way to get the client id (web, oauth/android) and set it into the config in the android app. but... for some reason, it shows this exception: `(16) Cannot find a matching credential`

Comment: btw, why is this the accepted answer? i think iss needed the respective explanation!

Answer (score 11):

You don't need the `credentials.json` file to add basic google sign in to your app

follow this url and click the `Configure a project` button to add the package name and key sha-1 fingerprint and you should be good to go

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

check the this google sample project for a full implementation

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin

Comment: credentials.json is for web applicsations