# Google-service.json is same as credentials.json?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am making an android application that needs Google sign in API integration, 
After configuring the Project I got credentials.json however all over internet people are referring to google-service.json. I am getting status code 10. I want to know whether google-service.json is credentials.json or I am making a mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

**No, they are not the same.**

The google-services.json file is necessary for Google sign-in. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397347/where-to-put-credentials-json-in-android-studio) (particularly the second answer) to help you get signed in.